# why my RouteParams in angular2 didn't refresh in angular2?

Tags: routes, angular

My RouteParams didn't work well when I click "edit" button.

[image: first view here]

in the first view I click the edit btn on the **bob row** 
and this is the second view[image: second view]

now i click the back button in the browser and it goes back to fist view. then i click the edit btn on the **pop row** and this is the third view(same as second view which is wrong)[image: third view should be pop data but it is not]

and I put some console to debug. this is the console log[image: console.log]

here is my code for the first view when i click the edit button, it fire the func and record the 1 and 3 records in the console.log picture

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import { Router, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';
import {MailingListService} from'../../services/mailing-list/mailing-lists.service'
import {Subscriber} from '../../models/subscriber/subscriber';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'subscriber-list-edit-view',
templateUrl: './app/components/subscriber-list-editor-view/subscriber-list-editor-view.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class EditSubscriberListViewComponent {

subscribers: Subscriber[];
id: string;
constructor(private mailingListsService: MailingListService, params: RouteParams, private router: Router) {

    this.init(this.id = params.get("id"));
}


init(id: string) {
    this.mailingListsService.getSubscribers(this.id).subscribe(x => {
        this.subscribers = x;
    });
}
//this is fired when click the edit button
editSubscriber(subscriber: Subscriber) {

    this.router.navigate(['Subscribers.Edit', { id: this.id, subscriber: subscriber }]);
    console.log(subscriber);//this print the first and third record in console.log
}



deleteSubscriber(subscriber: Subscriber) {

    this.mailingListsService.deleteSubscriber(this.id, subscriber)
        .subscribe(() => { this.init(this.id) });

}


}
```

here is my code for the second view after i click the edit button and jump to the edit view, it fire the constructor and record the 2 and 4 records in the console.log picture

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { Router, RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';  
import {Subscriber}from '../../models/subscriber/subscriber';
import {MailingListService} from'../../services/mailing-list/mailing-lists.service'

@Component({
selector: 'create-subscriber-view',
templateUrl: './app/components/subscriber-creator-view/subscriber-creator-view.html'
})

export class CreateSubscriberComponent {
subscriber: Subscriber;
id: string;
subscriberId: string;  
name: string;
phoneNumber: string;
email: string;
isActivated: boolean;
isBusy: boolean;
isEdit: boolean;
constructor(private mailingListService: MailingListService,private params: RouteParams, private router: Router) {
    this.id = params.get("id");
    this.subscriber = params.get("subscriber");

    console.log(params.get("subscriber")); //this doesn't work well,print the second and forth record in the console.log

    if (this.subscriber != null) { this.isEdit = true; this.name = this.subscriber.name; this.phoneNumber = this.subscriber.phoneNumber; this.email = this.subscriber.email; this.subscriberId = this.subscriber.id; this.isActivated = this.subscriber.isActivated;};          

}

create() {
    if (this.phoneNumber == null && this.email == null) { alert("either phone or email is required ! "); return; }
    this.isBusy = true;
    this.mailingListService.createSubscriber(this.id, {
        name: this.name,
        phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
        email: this.email
    })     
        .subscribe(() => { this.router.navigate(['MailingLists.View', { id: this.id }]) });  
}  

edit() {
    if (this.phoneNumber == null && this.email == null) { alert("either phone or email is required ! "); return; }
    this.isBusy = true;
    this.mailingListService.editSubscriber(this.id, {
        name: this.name,
        phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
        email: this.email
    })
        .subscribe(() => { this.router.navigate(['MailingLists.View', { id: this.id }]) });  
}
```

}

as you can see, the fourth record in console.log is not correct so i assume it is the params problem. but i don't know why and how to solve the problem.

and this is the routeconfig

```
 { path: '/MailingLists/:id/Subscribers/Create', component: CreateSubscriberComponent, as: 'Subscribers.Create' },
{ path: '/MailingLists/:id/Subscribers/Edit', component: CreateSubscriberComponent, as: 'Subscribers.Edit' },
```

create and edit use same component but different url.

Comment: What are the urls displayed on both cases ?

Comment: i dont think this one is the problem with `routeParams` definately its problem with your code. will you please provide any plnkr for the same may be ill help you.

Comment: Hi all: I edit my code and the url

Answer (score 0):

Because previously I pass my subscriber as an object and routeparams find the object by reference. That maybe the reason why it didn't refresh the data.

I have a working solution here. Simply do a JSON.stringify(subscriber) instead pass an object you pass a string.

```
editSubscriber(subscriber: Subscriber) {
    this.router.navigate(['Subscribers.Edit', { id: this.id, subscriberString: JSON.stringify(subscriber) }])//here

}
```

now, in the second component you get the string and do a JSON.parse()

```
 constructor(private mailingListService: MailingListService, private params: RouteParams, private router: Router) {
    this.id = params.get("id");
    this.subscriberString = params.get("subscriberString");            
    if (this.subscriberString != null) {
        this.isEdit = true;
        this.subscriber = JSON.parse(this.subscriberString);//Here
        this.name = this.subscriber.name;
        this.phoneNumber = this.subscriber.phoneNumber;
        this.email = this.subscriber.email;
        this.subscriberId = this.subscriber.id;
        this.isActivated = this.subscriber.isActivated;
    };          

}
```

Always remember your routeparams can be only type of string number boolean (primitive types?)